# Cant launch TOR process? [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:54: Permission denied

Tags: crash, tor

This is the error I get when trying to launch tor its been working running great for a month but suddenly It stopped working and i trying to kill the process and start it again now I'm getting this error:

```
Mar 29 12:08:04.057 [notice] Tor 0.4.2.7 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.11-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1f, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.4, and Libzstd 1.4.4.
Mar 29 12:08:04.057 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Mar 29 12:08:04.057 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Mar 29 12:08:04.058 [warn] Skipping obsolete configuration option "TransListenAddress".
Mar 29 12:08:04.058 [warn] CookieAuthFileGroupReadable is set, but will have no effect: you must specify an explicit CookieAuthFile to have it group-readable.
Mar 29 12:08:04.059 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:8080
Mar 29 12:08:04.059 [notice] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:8080
Mar 29 12:08:04.059 [notice] Opening DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:54
Mar 29 12:08:04.059 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:54: Permission denied
Mar 29 12:08:04.059 [notice] Opening Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9040
Mar 29 12:08:04.059 [notice] Opened Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9040
Mar 29 12:08:04.059 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Mar 29 12:08:04.059 [notice] Opened Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Mar 29 12:08:04.059 [notice] Closing partially-constructed Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:8080
Mar 29 12:08:04.059 [notice] Closing partially-constructed Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9040
Mar 29 12:08:04.059 [notice] Closing partially-constructed Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Mar 29 12:08:04.059 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Mar 29 12:08:04.059 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `Mar 29 12:08:04.059 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:54: Permission denied` something is already using port 54 it seems.

Answer (score 0):

`Mar 29 12:08:04.059 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:54: Permission denied`

Port 54 is already being used by something. If you already have an old TOR process using the port, use `sudo pkill tor` to remove it. If not, some other process is using the port. You can check this using netstat or other commands to check port availability.